# Android studio kotlin error : Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am trying to implement a room database for a league data but when I'm trying to compile, it's doesnt work. The error seem to be throw in the Database file. I hope you can help me

In the Dao, i select all the countryProperty and insert them in the database,

```
@Dao
interface CountryDataBaseDao {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM DatabaseCountryProperty")
   fun getData() : LiveData<List<DatabaseCountryProperty>>

   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   fun insertData(data : List<DatabaseCountryProperty>)
}
```

In the entity, countryProperty entity get the extra entity,

```
@Entity
data class DatabaseCountryProperty constructor(
    @PrimaryKey
      val id: String,
      val name: String,
      val imagePath: String?,
      val extra: DatabaseExtraCountry?)


    data class DatabaseExtraCountry constructor(
      val continent : String?,
      val subRegion : String?,
      val worldRegion : String?,
      val fifa : String?,
      val iso : String?,
      val iso2 : String?,
      val longitude : Double?,
      val latitude : Double?,
      val flag : String?) {
}

fun List<DatabaseCountryProperty>.asDomainModel() : List<DevByteCountryProperty> {
    return map {
            DevByteCountryProperty(
                    id = it.id,
                    name = it.name,
                    imagePath = it.imagePath,
                    extra = DevByteExtraCountry(
                            continent = it.extra?.continent,
                            subRegion = it.extra?.subRegion,
                            worldRegion = it.extra?.worldRegion,
                            fifa = it.extra?.fifa,
                            iso = it.extra?.iso,
                            iso2 = it.extra?.iso2,
                            longitude = it.extra?.longitude,
                            latitude = it.extra?.latitude,
                            flag = it.extra?.flag
                    )
            )
    }
}
```

In the Database,

```
@Database(entities = [DatabaseCountryProperty::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
   abstract class DataDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
      abstract val countryDataBaseDao : CountryDataBaseDao

   }

    private lateinit var INSTANCE: DataDataBase

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): DataDataBase {
     synchronized(DataDataBase::class.java) {
       if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
           INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                   DataDataBase::class.java,
                   "data").build()
       }
     }
     return INSTANCE
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors was that I didn't had the annotation embedded to declare the fact that the extra is a  sub_class. So the code is,

```
@Entity
data class DatabaseCountryProperty constructor(
  @PrimaryKey
  val id: String,
  val name: String,
  val imagePath: String?,
  @Embedded
  val extra: DatabaseExtraCountry?)


data class DatabaseExtraCountry constructor(
  val continent : String?,
  val subRegion : String?,
  val worldRegion : String?,
  val fifa : String?,
  val iso : String?,
  val iso2 : String?,
  val longitude : Double?,
  val latitude : Double?,
  val flag : String?) {
```

}

Comment: genius!  Thanks saved me some time chasing the wrong issue.  It errored for me on a Stateflow viewmodel in the XML code... and that was it.

Comment: So happy that I helped you !

Answer (score 0):

Add these in your build gradle.

1. id 'kotlin-kapt' in your plugin
2. ```
     kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"  in your dependencies
   ```

Just Do a Try